# How is the list class a subclass of collections.abc.Sequence in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, the `list` class seems to be a subclass of `collections.abc.Sequence` (which makes totally sense):

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
issubclass(list, Sequence)
# returns True
```

But the list type doesn't seem to inherit from `Sequence`:

```
dict.__mro__
# returns (dict, object)
```

So, how does this `issubclass(list, Sequence)` is working? How does it return `True`?

Comment: What version of Python are you running? I'm using Python 3.7.x and the issubclass returns False

Comment: Python 3.7.4 on Linux

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `collections.abc` types overload the `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` operators to check if the object has the expected interface, without requiring true subclassing. See [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119) which introduced abstract base classes; in particular the section on [overloading those two functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#overloading-isinstance-and-issubclass) for more. This is sort of the point of the `collections.abc` module. For example, if you define your own class that provides the expected attributes, Python will say that it is an instance/subclass of that type:

```py
>>> class MyClass:
...   __contains__ = 0
...
>>> from collections import abc
>>> issubclass(MyClass, abc.Container)
True
```

The point of checking if something is a subclass or instance of some other type generally is to check that it has the expected interface. In this case, `MyClass` does have a `__contains__` attribute, so it's assumed to conform to the interface. Of course in this example it doesn't actually conform to the interface: `MyClass.__contains__` is not a method, so your program will fail if you try to use a `MyClass()` object as a container. However, `issubclass()` and `isinstance()` will tell you that it is a container object. The usual duck-typing rules apply.

Comment: To be clear, *a* definition is sufficient to "fool" `issubclass`,  but a *valid* function definition is required for something like `x in some_instance_of_MyClass` to work meaningfully

Comment: @chepner of course. I added more to the end to make that more clear to readers, thanks!